# How to use apt-get to download multi-arch library?

Tags: apt, cross-compilation

Is it possible to force apt-get to download a multi-architecture binary of the library I want to install?

Or is apt-get not the right tool for this?

Answer (score 13):

@Tanasis's answer is correct, I have updated it for 2021 (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) for `arm64` and `armhf`.

1. Add your desired architectures as follows:

   `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`

   `sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64`
2. Create a new .list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`:

   `sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/arm-cross-compile-sources.list`
3. Add the default sources to that list with the architectures (armhf, arm64) prefixed as such:

   ```
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal main restricted
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates main restricted
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal universe
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates universe
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal multiverse
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-updates multiverse
   deb [arch=armhf,arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
   ```
4. Update `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include your default architecture (if it doesn't already), otherwise apt will try to use your newly added architectures in those sources which may cause errors as it did with me. Add `[arch=amd64]` for each line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

   `deb [arch=amd64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse`
5. Run `sudo apt update` and make sure you get no errors
6. Installing a package with the new architectures should be successful now:

   `sudo apt install libasound2-dev:arm64`

Comment: When I install a package like this, it seems that dependencies are not automatically installed, eg. `libflann-dev:arm64 : Depends: libhdf5-mpi-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed` and this is transitive up the dependency chain. is this expected.

Answer (score 8):

First to enable multi-arch

```
dpkg --add-architecture <arch>
```

Now setup apt-sources to add the new repositories of the new architecture(if you need)

now update your sources.list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install multi-arch packages via apt-get regularly but you have to specify which architecture you want to download

```
apt-get install package:architecture
```

example:

```
apt-get install gedit:i386
```

Comment: I ran `dpkg --addarchitecture arm64` but I got an error `dpkg: error: unknown option --add-architecture`. 

I tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462579/ubuntu-dpkg-add-architecture-i386-throwing-error-add-architecture-unknown) and echoed `foreign-architecture arm64` into `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`. I ran `sudo apt-get update` but ran into more errors: `Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-arm64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)`. What does this mean?

Comment: Or there's no arm64 in the Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Never mind the `dpkg --add-architecture` just move on and try to install just `apt-get install package:architecture`

Comment: Just to test this, I tried running `sudo apt-get install vim:arm64` but got `E: Unable to locate package vim:arm64`.

Comment: Any progress/fix on the arm64?

Comment: this worked well for me, thanks! i just wanted to add that to combine specifying architecture and version would be `apt download package-name:arch=version`

Comment: As a dreamer, I like the idea that `dpkg --add-architecture arm64` would be enough to achieve a working configuration. But in practice, I had to manually add the `sources.list` entries like Tansis suggested, as well.

Answer (score 7):

For `arm64` I am doing the following on the `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

**Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial) example:**

I mark all the current (default) repos as `[arch=<current_os_arch>]`, e.g.

`deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted`

And I added the following:

```
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial main restricted

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates main restricted

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial universe
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates universe

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial multiverse
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-updates multiverse

deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
```

Not sure if this is the corrent fix, but at least it seems to be working.

**Note**: Don't forget to add foreign architecture: `dpkg --add-architecture arm64`