# Unable to install packages for different architectures using Multiarch

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, multiarch

I've been following [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO) to set up my environment in order to install packages for arm64 architecture on my amd64 machine, but I haven't been able to do so.

I have added 'arm64' to my list of dpkg foreign architectures.

```
ubuntu:~$ dpkg --print-foreign-architectures 
arm64
```

I have added arch-qualified my apt-source so my sources now read as follows:

```
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb [arch=amd64,arm64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
```

When I run sudo apt-get update I get the following:

```
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [102 kB]                                                                            
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]                                                                                     
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [102 kB]                                                          
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease           
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages              
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe arm64 Packages
Hit:9 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x xenial InRelease
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse arm64 Packages
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [632 kB]
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages  
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11     Metadata [305 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [201 kB]        
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages            
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [171 kB]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [226 kB]    
Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages          
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,892 B]
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages                       
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Err:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages 
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,328 B]
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,136 B]
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [59.9 kB]
Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [53.2 kB]
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48.7 kB]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [69.1 kB]
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages 
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Err:23 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
Ign:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe arm64 Packages
Fetched 306 kB in 1s (172 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch     http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404      Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-    updates/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-    backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And finally, when I try to install the [libdbus-1-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libdbus-1-dev) library for arm 64, apt is unable to find the package.

```
ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libdbus-1-dev:arm64 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libdbus-1-dev:arm64
```

Unfortunately I'm fairly new to cross compiling. Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Comment: Hopefully this will give an idea where to start (after removing the foreign architecture because that is not the way): http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation#Ubuntu_Linux

Comment: @MichaelBay your link goes to a mostly empty page.

Comment: Any progress/news on this?

Comment: I am using this fix for now: https://askubuntu.com/a/994650/163353

Comment: This is a great and valid question, no answers!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use apt-get to download multi-arch library?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430705/how-to-use-apt-get-to-download-multi-arch-library)