# arm64 multi-arch docker build fails on apt update

Tags: apt, docker, multiarch, arm64

I'm trying to create a multi-arch container based on ubuntu 20.04. Docker build fails on `apt update` after the new architecture is added. This is my docker file so far:

```
# base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# create user
RUN useradd -rm -d /home/embed -s /bin/bash -g root -G sudo -u 1001 embed
RUN mkdir -p /home/embed/software
RUN mkdir -p /home/embed/data

# symlink python3 to python
RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

# install arm64 cross-compilation toolchain
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64
RUN apt-get update
...
```

After it reaches `apt-get update`, I get the following output:

```
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main arm64 Packages
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Ign:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main arm64 Packages
Ign:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse arm64 Packages
Ign:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted arm64 Packages
Ign:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe arm64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/multiverse/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.142 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

It seems that all arm64 repositories are either ignored or not found. I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953727/unable-to-install-packages-for-different-architectures-using-multiarch) that has the exact same problem, but no solution is provided.

Do I have to arch-qualify all the apt sources before doing an `apt-update` like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/994650/1041926) says? Is there a more automatic way that suits building a docker image?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You're using the wrong archive URLs.  `arm64` exists on ports.ubuntu.com not the main archive.u.c

Comment: @ThomasWard I realize that. I was wondering if there's a clean/correct way of doing it rather than manually arch qualifying the old ones.

Answer (score 3):

I still don't know if there's a better way of doing this but I basically did what's done [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430705/how-to-use-apt-get-to-download-multi-arch-library/994650#994650), but for 20.04. The Dockerfile is now:

```
# base image
FROM ubuntu:20.04

...

# add arm64 architecture
RUN apt-get update
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64

## arch-qualify the current repositories
RUN sed -i "s/deb h/deb [arch=amd64] h/g" /etc/apt/sources.list

## add arm64's repos
RUN echo "# arm64 repositories" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list

RUN apt-get update
...
```

Comment: Thank you, you saved me hours with this!