# Unable to build multi architecture docker image

Tags: 20.04, docker

I want to built a docker image on my Intel laptop. The image will be deployed on both x86/x64 and arm64 hosts.  The docker file uses `ubuntu:20.04` base image. I tried building the image with following command:

```
docker buildx build . --no-cache --progress plain --platform linux/arm64/v8,linux/amd64 -t mytag
```

But it fails with error:

```
#10 [linux/arm64  3/17] RUN apt update &&     apt install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common &&     add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test &&     add-apt-repository -y "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main" &&     add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa  &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     sudo     usbutils     libcanberra-gtk3-module ...*
#10 191.3 Reading package lists...
#10 195.6 E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#10 195.6 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
#10 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apt update &&     apt install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common &&     add-apt-repository -y ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test &&     add-apt-repository -y \"deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main\" &&     add-apt-repository -y ppa:deadsnakes/ppa  &&     apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     sudo     usbutils     libcanberra-gtk3-module ..." did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

Referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1307721/1084348) answer, I added following lines to my `Dockerfile`:

```
## add arm64 architecture
RUN apt-get update
RUN dpkg --add-architecture arm64

## arch-qualify the current repositories
RUN sed -i "s/deb h/deb [arch=amd64] h/g" /etc/apt/sources.list

## add arm64's repos
RUN echo "# arm64 repositories" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security universe" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But now it gives me following error:

```
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

#23 19.23 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
#23 19.23 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:3 and /etc/apt/sources.list:51
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:14 and /etc/apt/sources.list:53
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:24 and /etc/apt/sources.list:55
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:8 and /etc/apt/sources.list:52
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:59
#23 19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
#23 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100

#9 [linux/amd64  2/31] RUN apt-get update
#9 39.27 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [3553 kB]
#9 CANCELED
------
 > [linux/arm64 16/31] RUN apt-get update:
19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:54
19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:26 and /etc/apt/sources.list:56
19.24 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
19.24 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:34 and /etc/apt/sources.list:57
19.24 W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
19.24 W: Target Packages (restricted/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:44 and /etc/apt/sources.list:58
19.24 W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:46 and /etc/apt/sources.list:59
19.24 W: Target Packages (multiverse/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:48 and /etc/apt/sources.list:60
------
WARNING: No output specified with docker-container driver. Build result will only remain in the build cache. To push result image into registry use --push or to load image into docker use --load
Dockerfile:31
--------------------
  29 |     RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
  30 |     
  31 | >>> RUN apt-get update
  32 |     # Set environment variables to avoid interactive prompts during installation
  33 |     ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get update" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

What I am missing here?

**Update 1**

I forgot to tell that I was able to successfully build the image for the same architecture as my laptop (x86/x64 or amd64) with command:

```
docker build . --no-cache --progress plain -t mytag
```

The issue started when I tried to build for arm64 / multi-architecture.

**Update 2**

I tried by commenting lines corresponding to `404` error:

```
# RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal main restricted" >> /etc/apt/sources.list   
# RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
# RUN echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But still same error.

This was expected, as the `404` is occuring for amd64 packages and not arm64 packages:

```
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
#23 19.23 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/focal-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

But I am guessing why it is failing for amd64 packages as it used to successfully build the image before I added changes for arm64.