# add the line with xenial-updates

Tags: apt, arm, cross-compilation

This is a follow up question on [Cross-compile for armhf and install a static library](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061979/cross-compile-for-armhf-and-install-a-static-library)

In the accepted answer following is mentioned at the end,

> Clarification: Multiarch packages need to be installed with the same version on all architectures. So, you should have libudev-dev:armhf with version 229-4ubuntu21.4, but your current repository configuration does not include this version. **So, you should add the line with xenial-updates where this version is supported.**

I want to know how exactly I can do following?

> So, you should add the line with xenial-updates where this version is supported.

I am new to this so elaborated answer with examples will be helpful.

### Update 1 (trials as per comments )

with sources.list shown below I tried "apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}" its output is shown below. Error of "sudo apt install libudev-dev:armhf" is below.

sources.list file contents

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
```

output of apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}

```
root@ajey-HP-Laptop-15t-dy100:/etc/apt# apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}
libudev-dev:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.29
Version table:
 229-4ubuntu21.29 500
    500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
libudev-dev:armhf:
Installed: (none)
Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.29
Version table:
 229-4ubuntu21.29 500
    500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial-updates/main armhf Packages
```

output of sudo apt install libudev-dev:armhf

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libudev-dev:armhf : Depends: libacl1:armhf (>= 2.2.51-8) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libblkid1:armhf (>= 2.19.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgcc1:armhf (>= 1:3.5) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libkmod2:armhf (>= 5~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libselinux1:armhf (>= 2.0.65) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libudev1:armhf (= 229-4ubuntu21.29) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Update 2

Tried with following in sources.list

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe
```

still getting error as below for sudo apt install libudev-dev:armhf

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libudev-dev:armhf : Depends: libacl1:armhf (>= 2.2.51-8) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libblkid1:armhf (>= 2.19.1) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.17) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libgcc1:armhf (>= 1:3.5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libkmod2:armhf (>= 5~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libselinux1:armhf (>= 2.0.65) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libudev1:armhf (= 229-4ubuntu21.29) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

### Update -3

Tried with following sources.list but no use, problem not solved yet

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe

deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe

deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main multiverse restricted universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main multiverse restricted universe
```

Comment: `sources.list` shouldn't contain *only* `xenial-updates`. It should contain `xenial` and `xenial-security` as well.

Comment: @muru tried it but still not able to solve the problem.

Comment: I have corrected sources.list in Update 2.

Comment: Hmm, try adding `xenial-security` for armhf as well. Things in `xenial-updates` can depend on `xenial-security`, and `xenial-security` can depend on `xenial`. So if you use `-updates`, you need both the other two.

Comment: @muru tired it but problem not solved yet.

Comment: Then I guess you'll have to do the extreme version of what psiphi75 said and use only `xenial`, and remove both `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security`. This might break things, so I suggest using a fresh install of Ubuntu for that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118727/discussion-between-ajey-and-muru).

Answer (score 1):

The OP in that question edited it to include this:

> `apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}` outputs the following:
>
> ```
> libudev-dev:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 229-4ubuntu21.4
>   Version table:
>      229-4ubuntu21.4 500
>         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
>      229-4ubuntu21.1 500
>         500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
>      229-4ubuntu4 500
>         500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
> libudev-dev:armhf:
>   Installed: (none)
>   Candidate: 229-4ubuntu4
>   Version table:
>      229-4ubuntu4 500
>         500 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports xenial/main armhf Packages
> ```

Note that the "candidate" versions for both architectures are different, since the `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security` repositories have newer versions for `amd64`, but not for `armhf`.

@psiphi75 is saying that you should install the exact same version for both architectures, so including `xenial-updates` will cause a mismatch (as will `xenial-security` though). So their suggestion is to not include it in `sources.list` (modifying step 4 in their answer), and then install `libudev-dev` for both architectures.

**However**, according to [the packages index](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial-updates&keywords=libudev-dev), `libudev-dev` now has the following version for the following architectures in `xenial-updates`:

```
229-4ubuntu21.29: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x
```

So, since the same version is now available for both `amd64` and `armhf` in `xenial-updates`, you can include it in `sources.list`.

Comment: Tried few options for sources.list but could not get it working. Can you please help me with correct contents of sources.list for current situation of packages.

Comment: @Ajey examine your output for `apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}` - check if the candidate versions match. If they don't, then look at the list of versions for both and only include the repositories for which you get the same version.

Comment: Please see [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/wIW4IWs.png)
with sources.list shown in the image I tried "apt-cache policy libudev-dev:{amd64,armhf}" its output is shown in the image. Error of "sudo apt install libudev-dev:armhf" is also shown in the image.

Comment: Yeah, don't post screenshots of text. Edit your question, copy the text there and use code formatting: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I have now added contents in the question, please have a look.