# Installing libraries for arm64 on ubuntu bionic x64

Tags: apt, arm, architecture

I want to install arm64 libraries in my ubuntu bionic so I can link using cmake for cross compiling. Here's what I'm doing, based on https://askubuntu.com/a/994650/613425

```
dpkg --add-architecture arm64\
&& echo "deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic main restricted\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-updates main restricted\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic universe\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-updates universe\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic multiverse\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-updates multiverse\n\
deb [arch=arm64] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse"\
| tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

gives me

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/restricted/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/universe/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/main/binary-arm64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In /`etc/apt/sources.list` you have to add `[arch=amd64]` in front of the amd64 sources 
(Or your host's system arch if it's something else)
Example:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb-src [arch=amd64] http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
```

Comment: Not needed for the `deb-src` lines